page numbering for dompdf when content exceeds 1 page?
consider i use following to create html content for dompdf in codeigniter 3 controller method:
public function generatePageHtml($report_name, $title1, $title2 = null, $title3 = null, $content) { 
        $html .= '<div style="position: relative; z-index: 2; padding: 20px;">'; 
        $html .= '<div style="margin: 10px 25px 4px 5px;">'; 
        $html .= $content;
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 20px; left: 20px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; color: black;"> ' . $report_name .' - '. $title1 .' - '. $title2 . '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>'; 
        $html .= '</div>'; 
        return $html;
    }

and i use that in a for loop for each content fetched from model which includes variable columns of several sql tables:
foreach ($value as $sub_item) {
         $html_content .= $this->generatePageHtml($report_name,$translated_section, $translated_subtitle, null,$sub_item);
 }

i use convas as follow for page numbering:
$canvas = $dompdf->getCanvas();
  $font = $dompdf->getFontMetrics()->getFont('times', 'normal');
  $size = 10;
  $page_number_text = "{PAGE_NUM}";
  $canvas->page_text(
      820, 
      570, 
      $page_number_text, 
      $font,
      $size,
      array(0, 0, 0), 
      null, 
      null 
  );

in final, i should add a table of contents and related page numbers to generated pdf;
here some content could exceeds one pdf page (A4 Landscape); thus page numbering should consider that;
numbering is truely applyed on pdf;
but, as some contents exceeds one pdf page, the usual numbering failed considering that in true page numbering in TOC;
how should i extract title 1, title 2 and its page number to create TOC for pdf;
perhaps, if i could define each time what is the last page number when i run generatePageHtml, so i could be able to add numbering to TOC truely.
